# How can I tell Maven search only in intranet Repository(Artifactoy) and not in Internet

Tags: java, maven, configuration, repository, artifactory

I installed maven and Artifactory.

Artifactory has an internet connection.

I configured Maven in this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<localRepository>X:/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
<usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
<offline>false</offline>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>MY_Artifactory</id>
                <url>http://myServer/artifactory/repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>MY_Artifactory</id>
                <url>http://myServer/artifactory/repo</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

How can I tell Maven that it searches only in Artifactory and that it should try direct with local internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>local</id>
      <name>Local Artifactory</name>
      <url>http://url/for/artifactory</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
 </mirrors>
```

add this to settings.xml

Comment: id can not be local. It cannot build the effective settings. I replaced it with another id. I thinks it works now.

Comment: I gave +1 already and I am testing now if it rellay works. :-)

Comment: Do you have an idea for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392260/why-is-not-maven-plugin-run-at-build-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured profiles using below command you can call them.

```
 mvn clean install -P dev
```

The above will use `dev` profile .

**Edit:** Other way is you can override built-in repositories .

Please go through [this](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF20/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution) i feel it is helpful.

http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF20/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution

Comment: Active profile is already dev. Doesn't maven take it automatically?

Comment: sorry , missed that . it will pick that one by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use:

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

since you want to only resolve dependencies in the intranet only all configured repositories (also those in transitive dependencies and weird pom.xml's) should use your internal repository. Not only central.

Comment: Is it enough to disable the feature?

Comment: I mean is it enough to tell maven that it looks only in Artifactory.?

Comment: Do you have an idea for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392260/why-is-not-maven-plugin-run-at-build-lifecycle)

Comment: jepp. mirrofOf * will cause ANY artifact resolution to use the mirror (your artifactory server). the repsoitories in the settings.xml dont need a valid url at all since the mirror will be used.